# checking uniq constraints without using primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate only with Annotations. My table looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NetworkType",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"network_id", "type"})})

public class NetworkType implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "network_id", nullable = false)
    private long networkId;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private String type;
    ...
```

Currently when I write the same NetworkType twice, it throws an exception due to the UniqueConstraint (which is expected).

My thoughts are to just read the item first before checking. The problem is, my primary key is the Id, which I need because other tables references this table.

**What's the best way to query for item for the "network_id" and "type" to verify the combination doesn't already exist?**

I know I can do this with a Query manually, but is there a more Hibernate-y way of doing it?

**In general, what's the proper way to "get" an object without using the PK?** Are Criteria or Query the best way?

Answer (score 0):

`@UniqueConstraint` is **mainly used by database schema generation tools** to create the data base schema. If used, they will generate the table with the columns mentioned in the `@UniqueConstraint` having unique constraint defined.

`@UniqueConstraint` doesn't have any impact/usage during data manipulation.

If you wish to achieve unique constraint behavior on `network_id` and `type` columns and your schema is already created, **update your database schema to add the `unique constraint` on `network_id` and `type` columns.** as below:

```
   ALTER TABLE NetworkType
   ADD CONSTRAINT uc_network_id_type UNIQUE (network_id, type)
```

Hope this helps!